# How to ignore empty cell values for getRange().getValues()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am able to get the range values using getValues() and put it into a string by declaring the following variables in Google App Script

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test"); 
var range_input = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
```

However, I realize I am getting a lot of commas in my string probably from all the empty calls.

For example, if values are following

```
================
Spreadsheet("Test") Values

A1=abc
A2=def
A3=    
A4=
A5=
A6=uvw
A7=xyz
================
```

If I do msgBox, it gets something like below.

```
Browser.msgBox(range_input) // results = abc,def,,,,uvw,xyz,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Is there a way to remove the trailing commas so I get something like below?
(i.e. ignore the empty cells)

```
Browser.msgBox(range_input) // results = abc,def,uvw,xyz
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following result.

  - Input

    ```
    A1=abc
    A2=def
    A3=
    A4=
    A5=
    A6=uvw
    A7=xyz
    ```
  - Output

    ```
    Browser.msgBox(range_input) // results = abc,def,uvw,xyz
    ```

In the current stage, I thought that although the comprehensions of `var result = [i for each (i in range_input)if (isNaN(i))]` can be still used, it is not suitable for this situation as tehhowch's comment. Alto I think that `filter()` is suitable for this situation. In this update, I would like to update this by proposing other solution. If this was useful, I'm glad.

#### Pattern 1:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test"); 
var range_input = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var result = range_input.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  if (e[0]) ar.push(e[0])
  return ar;
}, []);
Logger.log(result) // ["abc","def","uvw","xyz"]
Browser.msgBox(result)
```

- In this pattern, the empty rows are removed by `reduce()`.

#### Pattern 2:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test"); 
var range_input = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var result = [].concat.apply([], range_input).filter(String); // or range_input.filter(String).map(String)
Logger.log(result) // ["abc","def","uvw","xyz"]
Browser.msgBox(result)
```

- In this pattern, the empty rows are removed by `filter()` and when `filter()` is used, the 2 dimensional array is returned. In order to return 1 dimensional array, the array is flatten.

#### Pattern 3:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test"); 
var range_input = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenCellNotEmpty().build();
var f = ss.getRange("A1:A").createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
f.remove();
var result = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText()).map(function(e) {return e[0]});
Logger.log(result) // ["abc","def","uvw","xyz"]
Browser.msgBox(result)
```

- In this pattern, the empty rows are removed by the filter, then the filtered values are retrieved.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Class Filter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter)

Comment: Dear Tanaike,

Thank you for your comments and wow your fast :-) This is exactly what I was looking for!  I will immediately start using your suggest.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry I didn't know about the 'accept' button until today :) It's now accepted.

Comment: I had no idea list comprehensions worked in Google Apps Script!

Comment: Array comprehensions should not be utilized - they are a now-deprecated language feature

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your comment. I had not been able to notice that situation. Thank you for letting me know. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I think that TripleDeal's answer should be as the solved answer. So I proposed other patterns.

Answer (score 35):

You can also use `filter()`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test"); 
var range_input = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var filtered_input = range_input.filter(String);
```

Comment: Hi Triple, thanks also for the suggest. I tried you suggestion and that also indeed worked! I like your code because its very clean and easy to understand.

Comment: You're welcome!
Oh and thanks for the up-vote, I now have more than 50 reputation, so I'm now finally able to comment on any question.

Comment: My pleasure. My up-vote is petty compared to your help  :)

Comment: Well, you can choose my answer as the correct answer to your situation if you want, that should be enough to make me even more happier than I already was.

Comment: Best answer so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested for efficiency, but for a simple removal of  multiple `,`s, you can use regex:

```js
const a=[['abc'],['def'],[''],[''],[''],['xyz'],['']];//simulate getValues()
const out =  a.join(',').replace(/,+(?=,)|,*$/g,'') //'abc,def,xyz'
const out2 = a.join('«').replace(/«+$/,'').split(/«+/) //flattened

console.log({out, out2})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that you want to **get multiple columns** with the `getValues()`, the `filter(String)` won't work, instead you have to create a custom filter function like:

```js
dataSheet.getRange("F3:H").getValues().filter(function(row) {
 return !row.some(cell => cell === '' || cell === null) 
})
```