# How to check if the cell is empty, if so skip it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I want to add 1 more line to check if the particular row is empty. If empty I want it to return.

```
    if (index === 0) return; // this to check header
    if (row[52]) return; // this to check if the row have data. if have it returns.
```

The full code for this part is below.

```
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('Google Doc');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder');
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('List');
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[52]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[4]} List` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues()` returns an empty string from blank cells, considering this, you might use the following expression:

```
row[52] === ''
```

`===` is used to compare value and data type. Using `==` will work too, it only compare value, it relies on JavaScript data type conversion rules. If you aren't familiar with these rules, use `===`.

Using just `!row[52]` as a conditional expression is tricky because when `row[52]` is equal to `''` or equal `0` and when it's `undefined` this expression returns `true`.

Related

- [How do I check for an empty/undefined/null string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154059/1595451)
- [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1595451)
- [How to ignore empty cell values for getRange().getValues()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44579300/1595451)

Comment: It works. I did try this as well and it works too

`if (!row[0]) return;`

Comment: just curious, why the triple sign? doesn't work with 2?

Comment: @RicardoAranguren See [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1595451)